# How to achieve text superlong processing when connecting to chatgpt using larravel

Tags: php, laravel

By rewriting the current data beyond the maximum limit of GPT, the request was made by segmenting the required text content, but without any effect. How to use the extension GuzzleHttp provided by larravel as the request method? There is also no indication on the document. I hope to get help here.